# What is the initial scroll container?

Tags: css, scroll

For a sticky positioned box properties like `top`, `right` [define](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-3/#stickypos-insets) offsets from  respective edges of the nearest **scrollport**. And this entity is [described](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#overflow-properties) by the spec as follows:

> These properties *[`overflow-*`]* specify whether a box’s content
> (including any ink overflow) is clipped to its padding edge, and if
> so, whether it is a **scroll container** that allows the user to scroll
> clipped parts of its scrollable overflow area into view. The visual
> viewport of the **scroll container** (through which the scrollable
> overflow area can be viewed) coincides with its padding box, and is
> called the **scrollport**.

Having such a plain DOM hierarchy as `html > body > div` when the `div` is sticky positioned, what would be its nearest scroll container? To put it another way, what's the box which gets those fancy scrolling arrows from the UA as long as the `div`'s content starts to exceed `100vh`?

The `overflow-*` properties of both `html` and `body` are computed to `visible` (tested in Chrome), so their boxes [are not](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#valdef-overflow-visible) scroll containers. So am I getting it right that the concerned box is *initial containing block*? But I can't find proof.

Comment: There's a couple of problems with it being the initial containing block.  First, the initial containing block is not a box, it's a rectangle, so it doesn't have a padding box and therefore can't fit the definition of a scroll container. Second, the initial containing block size is tied to the [actual viewport](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/#actual-viewport) whereas the scroll controls are tied to the [initial viewport](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/#initial-viewport). But the initial viewport isn't a box either, so also doesn't fit the scroll container definition.

Comment: @Alohci as to my question, in fact, I finally got content with [this](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#overflow-propagation) spec note: *..user agents must instead apply the `overflow-*` values of the first such child element [body] to the viewport.* and *If `visible` is applied to the viewport, it must be interpreted as `auto`.* So viewport is spruced up by scrollbars. As to the fact that viewport can't be considered a box.. well, who cares?

Comment: @Alohci BTW, it's an exciting thing that, on the one hand, box model is [described](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#box-model) through the document tree concept, so ICB can't be a box indeed. But how about [it](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#containing-block): *In CSS 2, many box positions and sizes are calculated with respect to the edges of a rectangular **box** called a containing block.*?

Comment: Yes. The term "box" really isn't applied consistently in the CSS specs especially CSS 2. The margin box, the border box, the padding box, the content box, the line box, the page box - none of these are "boxes" in the strict CSS 3 sense. If you see "box" unqualified in CSS 3 though, think the box model with its four nested rectangles.

Comment: As for who cares about the viewport not being a box, well I thought you were asking for a spec-level precise definition of what the initial scroll container was, and the spec definition of a scroll container is that it be a box. That's all.

Comment: The CSS 3 display spec says this of [containing blocks](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#containing-block) - "A rectangle that forms the basis of sizing and positioning for the boxes associated with it. Notably, a containing block is _not_ a box (it is a rectangle) ..."

Comment: @Alochi thank you for this citation. It took time for me to comprehend the difference. To my knowledge, containing block (which is not a [block](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#block-boxes)) just refers to a rectangular area the corresponding box taking up.